# the mouseup event on a picturebox

Tags: vb.net, events, picturebox, mouseup

I am trying to write a program that shows a series of seven pictureboxes (instructions, black background, image, black background, etc.) and this series is started off by a mousedown event on the middle mouse button (the scroll wheel) on the first picturebox. The person has to keep their finger on the wheel for the first four pictureboxes at least and maybe until the seventh. The pictureboxes fill the screen. The transition from box to box is governed by timeGetTime in winmm.dll.
The sequence part of the program, I am pleased to say, works very well.

However, I have two problems

1. I need to be able to stop this run of picBoxes and return to the
   first picBox if the middle mouseup happens before the fifth
   picturebox.
2. I need to record the time of the mouse up event when
   it happens in the fifth,sixth or seventh box.

The person then presses left or right mouse buttons and this works OK.
One main problem appears to be that the mouseup event is not working, but it works later in the program when the person has put their finger down on a left or right button and let it click up again.

After the sequence which is in the previous subroutine, which I have divided into sequenceA (picboxes 1-4) and sequenceB (picboxes 5-7). I have put:

```
Private Property sequenceA As Boolean
Private Property sequenceB As Boolean

Private Sub picBox2_mouseup(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles picBox2.MouseUp
   If MouseButtons.Middle Then
       If sequenceA = True Then
           picBox1.Visible = True
           sequenceB = False
           sequenceA = False
       End If
   End If
End Sub
```

I have been trying for days! And this code above, if it worked, would only tell me if the mouse went up on picBox2 but I need to know for picboxes 2-4.

Comment: TL;DR but you will need one or more module level variables to track the time of the mouse changes.  If the picture boxes dont fill the form you'll have to also monitor mouseevents for the form.

Comment: If your mousedown didn't happen on picBox2, you won't be able to handle mouseup on picBox2, etc. Why not use a single PictureBox and change the picture?

Comment: @DanVerdolino: You actually can do this. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Building on my comment, I've written some code which uses a single `PictureBox` to display all the images, which allows for `MouseUp` and `MouseDown` to be handled.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private currentImageIndex As Integer
    Private images As List(Of Bitmap)
    Private loopTimer As Threading.Timer
    Private timeForEachImage As Long = 500 ' ms
    Private stopTime As DateTime

    Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseUp
        If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Middle Then
            stopLoop()
            Select Case currentImageIndex
                Case 0 To 3 ' stopped before the 5th
                    changePictureIndex(0)
                Case 4, 5, 6 ' on or after the 5th
                    stopTime = DateTime.Now
            End Select
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseDown
        If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Middle Then startLoop()
    End Sub

    Private Sub startLoop()
        stopLoop()
        currentImageIndex = 0
        loopTimer.Change(0, timeForEachImage)
    End Sub

    Private Sub stopLoop()
        loopTimer.Change(Threading.Timeout.Infinite, Threading.Timeout.Infinite)
    End Sub

    Private Sub imageTimerCallback()
        currentImageIndex = Math.Min((currentImageIndex + 1), 7)
        If currentImageIndex < 7 Then changePictureIndex(currentImageIndex)
    End Sub

    Private Sub changePictureIndex(ByVal index As Integer)
        If PictureBox1.InvokeRequired Then
            PictureBox1.Invoke(New Action(Of Integer)(AddressOf changePictureIndex), index)
        Else
            PictureBox1.Image = images(index)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        images = New List(Of Bitmap)
        images.Add(New Bitmap("C:\...\img1.png")) ' load all your images in order
        images.Add(New Bitmap("C:\...\img2.jpg")) ' etc.
        loopTimer = New Threading.Timer(AddressOf imageTimerCallback)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite the answer of Dan I would like to point out how to handle the mouse events for multiple boxes.

The problem is, that when you press a mousebutton down on a control, the mouse gets captured inside of this control. Therefore only mouseevents from this specific control are handled as long as the button was not released again.

This can be changed by changing the .Capture property of the original control.
The following code creates a new picturebox when the mouse is pressed down on another picturebox and handles the mouseup event from the new one.

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseDown
    Dim pb2 As New PictureBox 'Create new picturebox
    With pb2
        .Name = "TheNewPicturebox"
        .BackColor = Color.Green 'Make it more visible
        .Size = PictureBox1.Size 'Set Size and Location over the old pb
        .Location = PictureBox1.Location
        AddHandler .MouseUp, AddressOf p2_MouseUp 'Add a handler for the MouseUp-event
    End With
    PictureBox1.Capture = False 'IMPORTANT: Releases the mouse from the old picturebox
    Me.Controls.Add(pb2) 'Add the new pb to the form
    pb2.BringToFront() 'Places the new control over the old one (z-order)
End Sub
Private Sub p2_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
    MessageBox.Show("Greetings from " & CType(sender, PictureBox).Name)
End Sub
```

This may be a point of origin for an implementation of your concrete problem.

Comment: Cool idea. He would also need to add a mouse down handler for the new picture box for the next run.

Comment: Yes, this answer is more a proof of principle in general. A solution with one PB would probably be preferable anyways. But the answer is important in other applications as well (think e.g. custom made drag&drop from one control to another).